# Project name is not shown on "my account -> applications"

Tags: android, google-api, google-console-developer

I created an android application that is using google api (only google drive, but it doesn't matter). I entered a desired name for this project in google console and it is shown in google sign in dialog when I request permissions from user. But when I opened my account to view applications to which I gave access I didn't found any app with my name. But I found app named "project-xxxxx", where 'xxxxx' is my project number.

I tried to search but didn't found any answer and in google api console it is not obvious what should I also set to show up desired project name instead of numbers.

Or maybe it is because my app is not published on google play?

UPD. Here is a screenshot
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek1Rv.png)

Comment: Images would be much helpful.

Comment: Are you talking about the project name in your phone or your console which has a different project name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I didn't notice that message on credentials tab that said to configure consent screen:

[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Wzm.png)

After I clicked it, it opened oauth consent screen settings and there I changed that default project-xxxx to something useful.

[oauth consent screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75nsX.png)

I also added a url to an icon. After saving, my changes immediately showed up in "my account -> permissions" page. Question closed.